# Can I connect a household heater to a 240V garage outlet?

Tags: electrical

My husband (not living) had a separate 240V outlet installed in the garage that he could plug his Snap-On truck in to charge. I just remember him talking about how he would plug in his truck (Snap-On dealer).

Anyways. I have a 120VAC 1500W infrared heater.  Can I use this outlet for that? I can't seem to plug it anywhere in the house because it trips every breaker.  House was built in 1976. No upgrade 3 circuits not counting the one in the garage. I don't want to do the wrong thing.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the receptacle in question please?

Comment: Can you clarify how the heater is actually helpful in the garage when it seemed that you wanted to use it in other areas of the house where you plugged it in and tripped the breaker?

Comment: A 1500W heater (nominally 12.5A) should be able to work on any standard 15A or 20A breaker as long as there is nothing else running on a 15A circuit or very minimal additional power draw on a 20A circuit. Circuits can only support 80% of their rating under continuous load--e.g.13A for a 15A circuit and 16A for a 20A circuit). Try to find a 120V 15A or 20A circuit that has nothing else connected to it and try running your heater. If it still trips the breaker, there is likely something wrong with your heater.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info and pictures to help you. If you can't add a picture, just add the URL and someone will be along to edit it in. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: It won't physically fit; that's the surest sign to "not do it".   Plug and socket keying is designed very carefully to assure that things which should plug in, can; and things which shouldn't can't. **Do any of these breakers that are tripping, do they have a TEST button on them?**

Answer (score 1):

A 220/240v single phase outlet (they are the same)  is not what you would want to plug a 120v 1500w heater into. If that heater is tripping a 15 amp breaker there is something wrong as it should only be drawing 12.5 amps. 
Most mobile power outlets are 120v 30amp or 240v 50 amp. In either case it would be a code violation to plug this heater in because both breakers are two large (even an adapter cord is used on the 240v)

Comment: What do you mean by "mobile power outlet"?

Comment: For rv’s 120v 30a is the most common (rolling stock plugins)

Comment: Ah. I hadn't made the connection between a Snap-On truck and a mobile home. Makes sense.